# Complex Django query

Tags: python, django

I have theses models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group')

class Group(models.Model):
    ...
```

Now I want a query that will give me back all the distinct `Group` where all the persons in each group have the position *worker*. So I will have all the groups with only workers in them. How to do that?

I started with:

```
groups = Group.objects.filter(person__position='worker').distinct()
```

But with this I have groups that have persons that are not *worker*.

For example my query should return group1 but **not** group2:

```
group1
    person1 -> position=worker
    person2 -> position=worker
    person3 -> position=worker

group2
    person4 -> position=worker
    person5 -> position=looser
    person6 -> position=sleeper
```

Comment: You mean you want to find `Group` models that *only* have `position` equal to `'worker'`, and no other values?

Comment: Exactly! I added an example to my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Group.objects.exclude(~Q(person__position="worker"))
```

**Edit:**

The above wasn't correct so here's my second try:

```
Group.objects.filter(
    Q(person__position="worker") 
    & ~Q(person__position__gt="worker")
    & ~Q(person__position__lt="worker")
)
```

I am unsure if this can be used with all databases. It works with my PGSQL installation.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It's mostly equivalent at `Group.objects.filter(person__position="worker")` because the NOT from the `exclude` cancel the NOT of the `~Q`. Both queries give the same result.

Comment: Oh, nice! Really interesting approach. I tried it and it works! I need to adapt it to my real models (they are definitely more complex than my exemple). But I'm pretty sure it will work. And with my real models I'm able to use `id` inside the `Q` queries so `lt` and `gt` are sure to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look into annotation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

I can't recall the exact syntax, but you should be able to annotate each Group with the number of Persons with position="worker" as well as the total number of Persons, then filter it to only the Groups where those two counts are equal.

Comment: Your idea seems good but unfortunately I'm not able to implement it. I can't find the right way to write it. As a matter of fact, I tried to solve this directly in SQL and I'm not able this way either...